# Find the word apostrophe and replace it with a double

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a provision that updates the records,
there is an input parameter @email
Problem: in some situations, email addresses with an apostrophe are sent to the parameter value,

and sql as you know does not understand the data value
Examples are: @email = 'Aiza'Mar', Al'Saad
As if in the beginning there is an apostrophe in the word, then find replace with double apostrophes

Comment: You should be binding strings to executable statements not concatenating them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select email,replace(email,'''','''''') from test;
```